# Database Design: how to avoid EAV?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Database Design: to EAV or not to EAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608759/database-design-to-eav-or-not-to-eav)

I'm modeling vehicle information. A vehicle can have 0 or more "equipment" (e.g. engine, wheels, spoiler, CD player, etc.). An equipment can have 0 or more "attributes" (e.g. an engine's "fuel type" might be "diesel").

I don't know in advance what these equipment are going to be (they will be defined by the user) much less what the attributes are going to be for these unknown equipment.

So, now the temptation is for me to use EAV. Am I heading in the wrong way? I'm worried I'll have to do something like this: find all vehicles where fuel type is diesel, etc. Sounds painful to me.

Any suggestions for alternative approach, if needed?

Comment: What is it supposed to do with entities? Search? Filtering? Sorting? Isn't it possible to create static set of tables (one table per entity) that fits all of them?

Comment: We already have a list of over 200+ possible equipment. Are you suggesting 200+ tables? Then a related "attributes table" for the main table? For example, an `equipment_engine` table with a related `equipment_engine_attribute` table?

Comment: I don't know if you can avoid it, but some attributes can be common enough that they could be stored separately (IE: engines, doors, wheels) from EAV.

Comment: @Aaron - the question is a bit more defined than originally posted as I now have a clearer picture of the requirements. Where the first question assumed just a handful of equipment with some attributes being known in advanced, this question assumes no knowledge of the equipment or its attributes. Bigger problem, IMO -- and I'd like to get a fresh perspective on possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules of thumb are:

1. If a key/value pair might be part of a where clause or manipulated through sql, it should probably be an appropriately typed column in the table rather than in an eav store.
2. If multiple key/value pairs are frequently combined, they probably belong in a separate table.